# Pygame: how do you write pygame.line without a draw

Tags: python, pygame

Okay, I am very new to `Python` and `Pygame`, but searching online is throwing up only information for `pygame.draw.line`.

What I would like to do is create many `pygame.line` that I can move with the same lines of code.

i.e.
This is the code I have for a rectangle

```
b1 = {'rect':pygame.Rect(240, 700, 20, 20), 'color':GREEN, 'dir':LEFT, 'jump':STILL}
```

which works, and I draw the `Rect` later in the code.

However, I am unsure how to create the same effect with `pygame.line`

```
f1 = {'line':pygame.line(0,704,4), 'color':GREEN, 'dir':STILL}
f2 = {'line':pygame.line(0,650,4), 'color':GREEN, 'dir':STILL}
```

These lines throw an error about `module` object having no `line` attribute.
As I said, I am very new, and so am unsure about a lot of the context and syntax in Python.

Answer (score 0):

My own answer to this problem is to ignore using `pygame.line` and instead continue to use `pygame.Rect` and create a rectangle of only a few pixels wide.

i.e.

```
f1 = {'line':pygame.Rect(0,702,480,2), 'color':GREEN, 'dir':STILL}
f2 = {'line':pygame.Rect(0,650,480,2), 'color':GREEN, 'dir':STILL}
floors = [f1,f2]
```